# Why is my preview empty?

Tags: support, editor

When I edit answers on SO, the preview (position marked with a red arrow in the picture below) is empty and the editor toolbar's icons are missing:

[image]

Since the "hide preview" link is showing, the preview should be visible.

Note: I'm using FireFox 52.0.2 (32-bit) on Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: The editor toolbar is also empty of all icons. This suggests that there's a JavaScript error somewhere that is stopping all scripts from running. It could be a blocked script on your end, or a badly cached version locally or on a proxy between you and us. What does the developer console say?

Comment: I see an exception in `analytics.js` in `function Ja(a)` when loading the page. It throws an "abort". When I click "edit"; however, there is no exception.

Comment: Does going over https and/or clearing the SO cache help?

Comment: I just cleared the browser cache while keeping the history and cookies. Now it works again. In Firefox: History > Clear Recent History... > Select the time range "Everything" and uncheck everything but "cache", and click "Clear now".  Please post your suggestion as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I suspect a badly cached JavaScript file (based on the editor toolbar not showing up) - clearing the SO cache should fix the issue if that is it.

To exclude anyone between yourself and our TLS termination points, try accessing over HTTPS (though I don't think that's it).

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/?